# Does the legend rule affect 2 creatures with the same general name?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have [Squee, Goblin Nabob](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=456746) on the battlefield. Does the legend rule apply if I then play [Squee, The Immortal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443034)?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The following is the "legend rule":

> 704.5j If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”

There's nothing concerning controlling two or more legendary permanents with similar names.

Comment: duplicate of https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33548/can-i-have-two-similar-legendary-creatures-on-the-field/33550#33550 ?

Comment: @Hackworth, Yup. I closed it as dup.